# Is there an easier way to import this data into a sql database?

Tags: sql, import, ssis

I'm trying to import a bunch of ach files and make a big sql table.  An ach file is a text file with transaction information arranged in columns.  The problem is that I need to add a date column.  Currently the date is only contained in the file name and header.  There are about 3000 files and each file is a different date.

I have basic knowledge of sql commands and how to query a database, but I just started learning about importing data for this project.  The only tool I found is the program called "import and export data" as a part of sql server 2012.  It allows me to import the text file and make it into a table.

The problem is that I have to import the text file and create the table.  Then I add a column for the date, do

```
update table
set date='date'
```

then I can combine tables with an insert command.  The do it again 3000 times.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can definitely do that in SSIS. Take a look here for the first part: enumerating files in a folder and importing them: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/. Build that and post back for more help. Just one important question: do all the files have the same number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a program that [can open all files in directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder)
2. Extend that program [to parse ach files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211382/parsing-text-file-separated-by-comma)
3. Extend that program [to get date from file name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737461/how-to-get-only-file-names-from-the-directory-not-the-entire-path)
4. Extend that program [to write to database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142806/how-to-insert-records-in-database-using-c-sharp-language)

I'd say it's 3 hours of work.

Comment: I appreciate your response, though I don't know anything about C#.  How complex of a thing is it to learn?

Comment: @user3634056 I believe it will be faster to learn limited amount of C# that will allow to write this program, compared to manually processing 3k of files.

Comment: Is there a recommended website or book to look at to get started?

Comment: You can do all those things in SSIS also.

Comment: If it can be done in SSIS, do you mind saying how, or pointing me to a place where I could learn it?

Comment: @ElectricLlama and how exactly would you extract date from file name  in SSIS?

Comment: @user3634056 start by downloading Visual Studio Express http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-web and SQL server http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062 then create project in visual studio, do steps 1 - 4 and you should be done.

Comment: If you go through the link I sent (a comment against your question) you'll see that the filename is captured in an SSIS variable, which you can subsequently use in your data flow and add to a table. Why don't you go through the demo linked in my other comment and add some more specific questions.

Comment: @ElectricLlama my apologies. I believe your answer is more correct than mine, I will leave my answer in case user does not have access to non Express edition of SQL Server, but otherwise you are absolutely correct and I am not. I suggest you post it as answer.

Comment: Not at all, there are many solutions for a problem and by all means in some circumstances yours is definitely more practical than mine. SSIS definitely has its limitations. In the end it's the OP's choice.